# Raspberry pi pico and I2C prtocol

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, raspberry-pi-pico

This is my code so far. It recognizes my IC and gets a reg addr and some random data.

```
import machine

sdaPIN=machine.Pin(0)
sclPIN=machine.Pin(1)
i2c=machine.I2C(0,sda=sdaPIN, scl=sclPIN, freq=400000)

devs = i2c.scan()
if len(devs) == 0:
    print("ERROR NO DEV FOUND!")
    exit(1);
dev = devs[0]

print("ADDR: ", hex(dev))

print(i2c.readfrom(dev, 10))
```

I would write a function to fit the description of the datasheet or is that normal i2c.
If not how do i send a ack package or singel packages at all to the bus?[this is a pic of the datasheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DxX8.png) https://dokumen.tips/documents/av2026pdf.html and there i found the hole thing. The thing is this isn't also the right ic mine is a av2011 but i didn't find a datasheet for it. And this is the output of the code above.

ADDR:  0x63
b'\xa3\xfd\x80,\xf2\x00\xd8\xf6AR'